# Append directive to DOM by click event

Tags: angularjs

i have an strange issue. I am trying to do on click add directive to DOM element.

```
var input = document.createElement("autocomplete");
angular.element(ev.target).append(input);
```

Where `ev.target` is event from mouse click. When i am inspecting code, directive is there, but never called. If i am adding it outside like `<autocomplete></autocomplete>`, without click, all works. Looks like angular don't see it.

Comment: It is not strange. you need to  compile DOM after adding directive, using $compile.

Comment: you need to compile that element using `$compile` & then add it inside a DOM? currently you haven't compiled it, that's directive isn't got initialized..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `$compile` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template
>   function, which can then be used to link scope and the template
>   together.

This will perform the compilation and linking of your new element that you insert as shown above (set directiveTag into action).

Beneath a similar piece of code to show the usage.

```
var newDirective = angular.element('<div directive-tag></div>');
element.append(newDirective);
$compile(newDirective)($scope);
```